# Android - Java - Intent to send facebook chat message (facebook disabled xmpp)

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, web

***Facebook deprecated xmpp api.

Is there a way to open an intent (or pass data to fb) to send chat message on android device?
Facebook & Messenger apps installed on the device.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to pass uri to the intent
>   Here **100005727832736** is the user id of the person who you want to
>   message to

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/100005727832736");
```

Here is my sample code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/100005727832736");

Intent toMessenger= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
try {
        startActivity(toMessenger);
    } 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Install Facebook Messenger",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

This is what worked for me and i **haven not tested** this for some time now.

Comment: Thanks... I will try it.

Comment: You can't because that is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy and you wouldn't want to get banned

Comment: @HammadNasir I just checked and it works 
Did you pass a valid profile id ?

Comment: The method to return profile id in facebook sdk is returning some other profile id which is different from profile id retrieved using https://findmyfbid.com Why is it so?

Comment: @nishon.tan I have asked a new related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46751331/6144372 Please reply.

Comment: Works only when sending to friends, not to random users.

Answer (score 0):

To launch **facebook app** let urlString = "fb://page/your_fb_page_id"

To launch **facebook messenger** let urlString = "fb-messenger://user/your_fb_page_id"

FB page id is usually numeric. To get it, goto [Find My FB ID](https://findmyfbid.com/) input your profile url, something like [www.facebook.com/edgedevstudio](http://www.facebook.com/edgedevstudio) then click "Find Numberic ID".

Voila, you now have your fb numeric id. replace "your_fb_page_id" with the generated Numeric ID

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString))
 if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) //check if app is available to handle the implicit intent
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Works only when sending to friends, not to random users.